# On click scroll to specific secton inside parent div overflow auto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a parent div with `overflow: auto` and fixed height. Inside this parent div, there are multiple sections. I want to scroll to these sections while clicking the left side navigation year anchor.

I have added jQuery but the section position is not correctly set.

[Please check JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vijaykaneriya/bveoaz8y/25/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".year-anchor").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    CurrentID = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.section-wrap').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#yearID' + CurrentID).position().top
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.milestone-section-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.navigation-ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
}

.section-wrap {
  width: 500px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="" style="height:100px">Content part</div>
<nav id="navigation"></nav>
<div class="milestone-section-wrap">
  <ul class="navigation-ul">
    <li class="timeline-year"><a class="year-anchor" href="2020">2020</a></li>
    <li class="timeline-year active"><a class="year-anchor" href="2019">2019</a></li>
    <li class="timeline-year"><a class="year-anchor" href="2018">2018</a></li>
    <li class="timeline-year"><a class="year-anchor" href="2017">2017</a></li>
    <li class="timeline-year"><a class="year-anchor" href="2016">2016</a></li>
    <li class="timeline-year"><a class="year-anchor" href="2015">2015</a></li>
    <li class="timeline-year"><a class="year-anchor" href="2014">2014</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="section-wrap">
    <section id="yearID2020" class="wide">
      <h1>2020</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
        industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="yearID2019" class="wide">
      <h1>2019</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
        industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
        industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="yearID2018" class="wide">
      <h1>2018</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
        industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
        industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
        industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="yearID2017" class="wide">
      <h1>2017</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
        industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="yearID2016" class="wide">
      <h1>2016</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
        industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="yearID2015" class="wide">
      <h1>2015</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ever and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </p>
    </section>
    <section id="yearID2014" class="wide">
      <h1>2014</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ever and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ever and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, vanilla JS does what you want. Just use [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".year-anchor").click(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    CurrentID = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#yearID' + CurrentID).get(0).scrollIntoView();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.milestone-section-wrap {
  position:relative;
}

.navigation-ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:0
}

.section-wrap {
    width: 500px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="" style="height:100px">Content part</div>

<nav id="navigation">

</nav>

<div class="milestone-section-wrap">

<ul class="navigation-ul">
          <li class="timeline-year"><a class="year-anchor" href="2020">2020</a></li>
          <li class="timeline-year active"><a class="year-anchor" href="2019">2019</a></li>
          <li class="timeline-year"><a class="year-anchor" href="2018">2018</a></li>
          <li class="timeline-year"><a class="year-anchor" href="2017">2017</a></li>
          <li class="timeline-year"><a class="year-anchor" href="2016">2016</a></li>
          <li class="timeline-year"><a class="year-anchor" href="2015">2015</a></li>
          <li class="timeline-year"><a class="year-anchor" href="2014">2014</a></li>

        </ul>
        
        
        <div class="section-wrap">
            <section id="yearID2020" class="wide">
  <h1>2020</h1>
  <p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </p>
</section>

<section id="yearID2019" class="wide">
  <h1>2019</h1>
    <p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </p>
    <p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </p>
</section>

<section id="yearID2018" class="wide">
  <h1>2018</h1>
    <p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </p>
    <p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </p>
    <p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </p>
</section>
<section id="yearID2017" class="wide">
  <h1>2017</h1>
    <p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </p>
</section>
<section id="yearID2016" class="wide">
  <h1>2016</h1>
    <p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </p>
    <p>
  Lorem ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </p>
</section>
  <section id="yearID2015" class="wide">
  <h1>2015</h1>
   <p>
  Lorem ever  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </p>
</section>
  <section id="yearID2014" class="wide">
  <h1>2014</h1>
    <p>
  Lorem ever  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </p>
    <p>
  Lorem ever  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </p>
</section>
        </div>


</div>
```